# how do i fix my grappling hook script bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, boolean

im making a game similar to karlson and struggling to fix this line of code to stop a bug
the bug is the grappling gun stuck in grappling mode while the player is not holding down the mouse button
the code i want to do is an if statement to check if the bool is true and Input.GetMouseButtonUp is not happening

```
***if ((bool)IsGrappling = true) && (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))){
    StopGrapple;
}***
```

here is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (IsGrappling == true && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    StopGrapple;
}
```

OR

```
if (IsGrappling && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    StopGrapple;
}
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: error CS0019 object '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'bool'

Comment: nvm fixed the CS0019 Error by adding () after Isgrappling thanks man you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

I write the difference between these three codes here.

**Input.GetMouseButton**: The function is executed continuously as long as the key is pressing.

**Input.GetMouseButtonDown**: When you press the mouse button, only the first frame.

**Input.GetMouseButtonUp**: When you release the mouse button, only the first frame.

the operator `!=` and `!` in c# Can reverse the condition. For that case:

```
    if (IsGrappling && !Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: thank you that can help me make better code later